# How to execute a perl command only between particular part of the file

Tags: regex, perl, ksh

Here is my input file

```
    ^A{1:IRVTUS30XXX}{2:I300dfaffaefa}{3:fewfa]}
    :15A:
    :20:1234556
    :22:dsafas
    dsafafaf
    erwfafgr
    :23:fewfd
    :24:firh
    :60:uncenjnjcdv
    :72:uenuernfk
    12345
    -}^C^A{1:IRVTUS30XXX}{2:I304dfaffaefa}{3:fewfa]}
    :15A:
    :20:1234556
    :22:dsafas
    dsafafaf
    erwfafgr
    :23:fewfd
    :24:firh
    :60:uncenjnjcdv
    :72:uenuernfk
    12345
    -}^C^A{1:IRVTUS30XXX}{2:I306dfaffaefa}{3:fewfa]}
    :15A:
    :20:1234556
    :22:dsafas
    dsafafaf
    erwfafgr
    :23:fewfd
    :24:firh
    :60:uncenjnjcdv
    :72:uenuernfk
    12345
    -}^C
```

Here I want to delete few lines with the below commands. If the incoming message is Type 300 (Depending on this tag in the first line 2:I300) I need to execute 1st command ONLY for that message that is between ^A and ^C in which pattern I305 should be there. Sameway for I304 i want to execute 2nd command and for I306 i should execute 3rd command.

```
     1) perl -i -pe 's/:20:(.*)\r\n//g' (for Type 300)
     2) perl -i -pe 's/:22:(.*)\r\n//g' (for Type 305)
     3) perl -i -pe 's/:(15A|15B):(.*)\r\n//g' (for Type 306)
```

Somehow I need to read the file as message by message i.e starting with ^A and ending with ^C

Please note that I need to do inplace replacement with the perl command and not to create any temporary files because there are few special characters which i want to retain in the file.

Comment: Creating temp files does not influence special characters. `perl -i` creates a temp file behind the scenes, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This is a riciculous file format, but it can be parsed nevertheless.

If each section ends with `^C`, we can use that as the *record separator* `$/`, which is a newline by default:

```
use strict; use warnings;

local $/ = "-}\x03";  # ^C
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  ...;
}
```

Now inside that loop, we parse the input, e.g:

```
# parse headers
s/\A\x01// or die "Section must start with ^A";
my ($headers, @lines) = split /\n\K/;  # \Keep the newline
my %headers = $headers =~ /\G\{ ([0-9]+) : ([^\}]+) \}/xg;

# extract the type:
$headers{2} =~ /\AI([0-9]{3})/ or die "Couldn't extract type";
my $type = $1;

# depending on the type, select a filter that matches forbidden lines
my $filter = {
  300 => qr/\A:20:/,
  305 => qr/\A:22:/,
  306 => qr/\A:15[AB]:/,
}->{$type};
$filter //= qr/(*FAIL)/; # matches never

print $headers;
# print out all lines that don't match this filter:
print for grep !/$filter/, @lines;
print "-}\x03";
```

This code is untested, but you should be able to adapt it.